# Как отменить (откатить) действие git pull?

Tags: git

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение проблемы:

Есть две ветки: `sphere` и `tags`.

Я находился в ветке `sphere` и случайно сделал `git pull origin tags`, потом, заметив, что написал неправильно, и не посмотрев, что мердж прошел с конфликтами, сделал `git pull origin sphere`, и у меня в ветку влились все новые изменения из `sphere`.

Как мне вернуть код к состоянию до первого `pull`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git reset --hard
git checkout sphere
git reflog
# Находите хэш коммита, в котором вы находились до первого pull-а.
# Будет что-то вроде "8f05e00 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to sphere"
# или "4c31200 HEAD@{10}: commit: Awesome feature implemented."
git reset --hard [нужный хэш]
```

Ну и я бы не рекомендовал использовать "git pull" вообще, потому как эта команда берет на себя слишком много функций и ее поведение неочевидно. Рекомендую разобраться поподробнее, как работает git, и использовать fetch + merge или fetch + rebase. Я лично предпочитаю второе, но это дело вкуса.

Comment: А первый git reset --hard (без хеша) делать в ветке tags? Если да, то зачем?

Comment: Это нужно, чтобы очистить дерево от незакомиченных изменений, которые могли остаться от прошлых pull-ов (merge конфликты). Если таких изменений нет, то команда не сделает ничего. С "грязным" деревом не получится сделать checkout sphere, а для последней команды мы должны находиться на sphere.

Comment: а я первый раз не делал git reset --hard (без хеша) - сделал git stash. Потом можно будет вернуться и продолжить работу в этом месте(что бы не терять данные) -- https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5

Comment: В крайнем случае можно вместо `git pull`  использовать алиас на `git pull --ff-only`, это исключит возможность неожиданного мержа.

Answer (score 2):

Если прям на предыдущее состояние:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

- HEAD@{0} - текущий коммит (рабочий стейт)
- HEAD@{1} - коммит перед текущим коммитом
- HEAD@{N} - N как номер коммита от текущего

**--hard** сбросит все изменения отслеживаемых файлов! Если исправления всё же нужно сохранить - просто не указывай этот ключ...