# Как отменить (откатить) действие git pull, если репозиторий не имеет ветки?

Tags: git

На рабочем сервере нет ветки, и все изменения мы подгружаем командой `git pull origin ветка с gitlab`, я находил инструкцию, но как я понял, там нужно находиться на своей ветке. Смогу ли я совершить откат через такой порядок действий?
`git reset --hard`
`git reflog`
`выбор нужного коммита`
`git reset --hard [нужный хэш]`
Или нужно как-то иначе это делать?
Прошу отнестись с пониманием, так как неудачные эксперементы мне не простят, поэтому нужен ваш совет)

Comment: Нет какой ветки? Что такое "своя ветка"?

Comment: ну вот получается в вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/361124/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-git-pull

Comment: Пишут, что решение git reset --hard
git checkout sphere
git reflog
# Находите хэш коммита, в котором вы находились до первого pull-а.
# Будет что-то вроде "8f05e00 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to sphere"
# или "4c31200 HEAD@{10}: commit: Awesome feature implemented."
git reset --hard [нужный хэш]

Comment: А если у меня есть только ветка, с которой я сделал git pull, как тогда сделать откат? Вот в чём вопрос

Comment: я просто не силён в гите, поэтому вопрос сложно составить граммотно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как тогда сделать откат?

да как и обычно:

```
$ git reset --hard хэш-нужного-commit-а
```

при этом в вашем рабочем каталоге будет развёрнуто содержимое того объекта типа tree, на которое ссылается указанный вами объект типа commit.

Comment: Спасибо большое)